# Multiple databases in same DB server access on Apache Superset?

Tags: python, apache-superset

In this post, it asks the possibility to query two different database servers.

[Multiple database access on Apache Superset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413246/multiple-database-access-on-apache-superset)

> I am looking to use Apache Superset and am considering if it will
> allow for me to connect to both POSTGres and MSSQL at the same time.
>
> There might be instances of creating queries from both databases
> however, i cant figure out based on the API documentation if this can
> be done.

I have two databases **in a single PSQL database server**. I can set up a user with permission on both databases. Can I create queries to both databases in the same PSQL server?